# Animating an element on window resize fires late

Tags: jquery

I am checking the window height on resize and animating an element if it is within a certain height. However, the function fires late, usually 4 or 5 seconds after I have finished resizing the browser window. I need it to fire as soon as I've finished resizing. While I am resizing would be even better. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Code is:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    adjustPanel();
});

adjustPanel = function() {
    if ($(window).height() > 920) {
        $('#search-board-wrap').animate({
            height: 795,
            marginTop: 795
        });
    } else {
        $('#search-board-wrap').animate({
            height: 650,
            marginTop: 650
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous animations keep running as the new ones are triggered, so your animation queue is probably filling up as the resize event triggers over and over.

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the current animation and clear the queue:

```
$('#search-board-wrap').stop(true, true).animate(...
```

Honestly, I would just CSS media queries and get rid of all of that JS:

```
#search-board-wrap {
    height: 795px;
    width: 795px;
}

@media all and (max-height: 920px) {
    #search-board-wrap {
        height: 650px;
        width: 650px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thank you. Also extra thanks for the CSS suggestion too.